# Приобретение реальных навыков в программировании

Tags: java

Появилась потребность в приобритении практических навыков в програмировании (язык Java). 
Т.к. прочтением разной литературы + статей, на одних задачах по ООП далеко продвинуться крайне сложно, ведь зачастую даже от juniora требуется знание сторонних технологий, фреймворков.

Хотелось бы узнать какой-нибудь ресурс, где таких вот начинающих людей берут либо на проекты open source, либо просто дают хорошие практические задания, [например как эти задания](http://mexmat.sgu.ru/sites/chairs/prinf/materials/java/maintask.htm).
Стоит цель самосовершенствования в программировании.

Подскажите что-нибудь, как быть, что делать. В большей части интересует web-программирование.

Comment: Уточните, что подразумеваете, ибо язык и программирование как таковое отделены друг от друга. Вы можете совершенствовать навыки программирования или навыки программирования имено на Java. Я бы рекомендовал первый подход, так как нужно иметь знания независимые от языка.

Comment: Именно на Java. Был бы школьником - решал бы задачки олимпиадные, времени то было бы навалом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пара задач.

1. Написать сайт на JSP/JSF, можно копнуть EJB.
2. Прикрутить к нему AJAX и MySQL/Oracle DBMS/подставить свое.

Думаю, этого для джуниора достаточно.

PS. Все это Java EE.

Comment: Поддержу этот ответ. Обычно веб приложение имеет такие слои: 1) client side, 2) server side, 3) DB. Выбираете для себя любую тему для сайта и пишете :) Я бы посоветовал JSF+MySql/Oracle. JSF оч просто изучить, SQL тоже не проблема. Потребуются минимальные знания html.

Comment: Спасибо, обучение дается просто, если возникают проблемы и самому нужно в этом разобраться, это откладывается в голове. Плохо что при самообучение написанный код никто не сможет проверить, дать по шее и показать как должно быть правильно.

Comment: правильно мыслите. но сначала лучше какое-то время писать так (чтоб мозг не отвлекался на слишком большой набор правил и ограничений).  
чуть позже можно будет почитать книжки про паттерны проэктирования и чистый эффективный код (есть несколько умных книжек на эту тему)  
следующий шаг, - (А) смотрите спустя пару мес в свой старый код и ужасаетесь. все преписываете. когда закончите переписывать все програмики. возвращаетесь к пункту (А).
читаете умную книжку по рефакторингу которая говорит что не надо этим злоупотреблять.
регаетесь наконец на девелоперском форуме и выкладываете свой код

Comment: Потом читаете, понимаете, что до совершенства еще далеко и исправляете ошибки.

Answer (score 3):

Для практики в web-приложений на java рекомендую пройти этот практический курс http://www.java-course.ru/students/students.php. Познакомитесь и с ЕЕ и с популярными фреймворками (Spring, Hibernate).

Comment: Очень классный сайт, обязательно попробую пройти этот курс... думаю вечером после работы 1-1.5 часа уделять этому времени, толк будет. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Если интересует именно Web, то я бы порекомендовал начать с создания собственного сайта. Не важно, будет ли его кто-нибудь посещать, главное, что вы сможете сами ставить себе задачи (это ведь ваш сайт и вы знаете, как он должен выглядеть), и сами же сможете их реализовывать.

Думаю бесплатный хостинг на php найти не трудно, а большего для начала и не надо.